# Nodejs,mongodb - using $nin or $in for object ids or _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object

I am using `Nodejs`, `mongodb` database.  We can use `$nin` like this

```
Model.find({ uname : { $nin : ["sachin","saurav"] } }....
```

above words for normals elements like `uname` and others. But for object ids(_id), ..

```
Model.find({_id : {$nin : ["6534767457dfgbyb23","wtvwt3wy5etvdh"] } } ...
```

above line not giving error, it is showing correctly..

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var a = new ObjectID("sdfsdznfsdz");
var b=new ObjectID("sdfjwneufhq2rfwefsd");
Model.find({_id : { $nin : [a,b] } }...
```

above also not giving error...

The problem is, I cant write manually like a,b,c,d...

I have to store all those a,b,c,d... in some variable in some correct format, and have to do like this

```
Model.find({_id : {$nin : variable } }
```

or

```
Model.find({_id : {$nin : [variable] } }
```

I tried this

```
var string = a+","+b //this didnt work, error : invalid object id
var string = "nfw34qfhrs9"+","+"u89tgngnfdb"  //this also same error
var string = "\"jn4tr43r\""  +  "," + "\"ansfuw37fe\""  //this also same error
```

What should I do? the thing is, I should get all items except those items with those `_ids`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way $nin works in mongo is that it takes an array of values to check.

The code:
`var string = a+","+b` Doesnt make this a valid array. as you're creating a string with the value `sdfsdznfsdz, u89tgngnfdb`

So $nin is treating the array as that value, not the way you're trying to implement.

Solution to do what you want is to create an array with those values.

So something like:

```
var ids = new Array( new ObjectId("1124edcef241"), new ObjectId("56943decfeca845") );

// Dont put [ ] as a parameter. Just send a variable thats an array     
Model.find( {_id : { $nin : ids } } ); 
...
```

Just incase you're a tad hazy regarding arrays, I suggest having a read of this:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: ur code working, but the situation is, i have a string str="nfsdfnskdjnjdf","ksjdngdfg","gseggxfzgd".... .This can have many inner strings,not just 2. From this, how can i get the array as you told me, please tell me that one. Thanks

Comment: `var str="nfsdfnskdjnjdf,ksjdngdfg,gseggxfzgd";
var ids = str.split(","); `

// ids is now an array from splitting the ,

Answer (score 5):

Not able to comment yet, but just wanted to add here that `new ObjectID()` wasn't working for me, but `new ObjectId()` (lowercase d) did work. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have since earned the privilege to edit and comment, so this comment is no longer relevant, but the accepted answer's code is now copy/pasteable!